# Is YUI Compressor useless for ExtJS app minification

Tags: extjs, yui

My manager wants me to look into initially using YUI Compressor to minify our ExtJS 4.2 app.

So I wrote a python file to concatenate all my ExtJS app files into a single file, and then minify that one file with YUI Compressor.

But I get errors related to objects not found, because order matters with JavaScript.

So for an app with many files, with multiple developers adding new files, it seems questionable whether YUI Compressor can be effectively used to minify ExtJS apps.

Is this true, or am I missing something?

Comment: I work on an older Ext web app, that uses YUI. It only works if you have your files organized in a certain manner.  I don't see a strong reason for using YUI in your scenario over Sencha CMD.

Answer (score 1):

YUI Compressor is must-have tool in the deployment process because it reduces js and css files in about 40%.

In your case you should use YUI Compressor AFTER you compile your ExtJS app into one js file. This is not effective to compress dozens of tiny files before concatenating them.

Of course the order of files for concatenation matters. It is based on dependency requirements declared in each file (which is actually ExtJS class).

I was tired to use Sencha.cmd because it's huge, inconvenient to install on servers, hard to automate and integrate into deployment processes.

I developed my own tool Extapp which makes the ExtJS applications builds. It requires java jre environment to run jar file.

Extapp : https://github.com/liberborn/extapp

Answer (score 0):

Using YUI is not useless, the problem lies with concatenating files without analyzing the dependencies between them.

Comment: Yes, but I'm thinking analyzing the dependencies of a complex ExtJS app might make using YUI Compressor difficult. YUI Compressor may be fine for simpler apps, but how can one analyze dependencies other than manually?

Comment: Yes, I actually want to use Sencha Cmd, but then I have to think about  does it need to be manually installed on build machines, or just downloaded to any machine for automated build processes.

Comment: Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: I would love to use Sencha Cmd. But these two things might prevent me from doing so:

1) I think Sencha Cmd needs to be installed manually, at least on Windows machines. This reduces our flexibility of allowing everyone to easily pull from git and build entire app.

2) Sencha Cmd is not compressing all the files in my app, in fact, almost none:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthre...80#post1028280

Comment: So my manager has become frustrated with my attempts to get Sencha Cmd to work. I get close, meaning I can successfully do sencha app build, and the code is minified, but when I try to use the generated minified file I get run-time errors, like there are unresolved dependencies.